# How to display tasks based on condition and user in a view

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements, model

I want to check each task that is stored in the model and is supposed to be displayed based on the value stored in the condition field. When I am checking each task during display, if the value inside the condition is equal to True, I want that task to be displayed for all users except users with usernames [‘Electric_Motor_Winding’, ‘Electrical_Panels’, ‘Seller’] until three months after being saved. If the condition is equal to False, I want that task to be displayed only to the user who saved it and only on the day it was saved.

So for displaying tasks, tasks must be checked for the date and user they were saved by and then checked for the value of the condition. If the value of the condition is equal to True, that task should be displayed for all users except users with usernames [‘Electric_Motor_Winding’, ‘Electrical_Panels’, ‘Seller’] until three months after being saved. If the value of the condition is equal to False, that task should only be displayed on the day it was saved and only to the user who saved it.

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    ordering = ['-posted_time']

    def get_shamsi_time(self):
        timezone.activate('Asia/Tehran')
        now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        shamsi = jdatetime.datetime.fromgregorian(datetime=now)

        #if shamsi.month <= 6:
        #    now += timedelta(hours=1)
        #    shamsi = jdatetime.datetime.fromgregorian(datetime=now)

        return shamsi

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            #exclude_users = ['Electric_Motor_Winding', 'Electrical_Panels', 'Seller']
            #context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].exclude(user__username__in=exclude_users)
            pass
        else:
            shamsi_today = self.get_shamsi_time().date()
            if self.request.user.username == 'Electric_Motor_Winding':
                if 15 <= shamsi_today.day <= 30:
                    last_month = shamsi_today - timedelta(days=45)
                else:
                    last_month = shamsi_today - timedelta(days=30)
                context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user, posted_time__gte=str(last_month))
            elif self.request.user.username == 'Electrical_Panels':
                one_weeks_ago = shamsi_today - timedelta(days=7)
                context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user, posted_time__gte=str(one_weeks_ago))
            elif self.request.user.username == 'Seller':
                context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user, posted_time__date=str(shamsi_today))
            else:
                context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user=self.request.user, posted_time__date=str(shamsi_today))

        context['count'] = context['tasks'].filter(condition=False).count()

        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area') or ''
        if search_input:
            context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(
                service_receiver__contains=search_input)

        context['search_input'] = search_input

        return context
```